# How to find out maximum number of likes and comments in facebook using Graph api

Tags: php, facebook

I want to retrieve the profile ids from my friends list those who comment and like most of the stuff I put on my wall.

So far I have retrieved a list of 30 friends who share the maximum mutual friends with me.

Now I need to sort these 30 again based on comments+likes.

I use php.

EDIT:

Any specific answers with Code sample is greatly appreciated

Comment: Good Question Karthik +1 for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi First you need to query the [Link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/links/)table using [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/). This will return you whole objects that you has posted. Then you just need to again query to [Like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) table. It will return you user id's who likes that page. Then you can compare those user id's with your user id's. i hope it will work ;-)

Comment: I got it now :) From the link table we only get the links we post and not all the status updates. Even then this is good enough :)